# This Value is Not a Function and Cannot be Applied F#

Tags: f#

I have been trying to write a program in F# which takes two values (a tuple): a number and a string. Depending on whether the string tells the program to add or multiply, it will add or multiply the input number with all the integers from 1 to that number (i.e. 1..n).

Here is the code

```
let addormult (n:int, what:string) = 
    if what = "multiply" then 
       let rec product n = 
           if n<1 then 0
           else n*product(n-1)
       printfn "%A" product
    elif what = "sum" then
         let rec sum = 
             if n<1 then 0
             else n + sum(n-1)
         printfn "%A" sum
```

However, every time I try to run this function, I get the error

> "This value is not a function and cannot be applied."

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess, you forgot to call the function

Comment: Instead of `product(n-1)`, try `product n-1` (though I am not sure about the order of operations here). I think the parenthesis are trying to turn it into a 1-value tuple.

Comment: in addition, you do not consider the option when `what <> "mul" && what <> "add"`

Comment: if fix it, you got: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yOaITi

Comment: but you will still have an incorrect result when multiplying. You need to return `1`, I suppose.

Comment: @FoggyFinder I have called the function. Also, can you explain what we mean in your last comment

Comment: @Max already gave the answer. Now you realized what your mistake was? If not, I'll try to explain.

Comment: Since you are just starting to learn F#, I would advise you to join [F# Software Foundation](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join) and when you have 20 reputation points, you will be able to join [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f) although it is not as active as F#-slack.

Comment: Note the recursive functions are not _tail recursive_ so can result in stack overflow for large enough N.  Better to do with a regular mutable variable and an imperative loop.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37010/171121 for an example of how to do it tail-recursively (in python).

Comment: @ClementDecker If one of the answers helped you resolve the issue, please remember to select it. :)

Answer (score 8):

In this part of the code:

```
let rec sum = 
    if n<1 then 0
    else n + sum(n-1)
```

`sum` is defined as a *value* because it takes no arguments. The third line attempts to call it as a function (`sum(n-1)`), which isn't possible because it isn't a function.

Add an argument to the function, e.g.

```
let rec sum x = 
    if x<1 then 0
    else x + sum(x-1)
```

Here I took the liberty and replaced `n` in that function body with `x`, although I don't know if that's what you want to do. It compiles, though.

Comment: I applied the suggestions, and I am getting the right value now. However, for some reason F# interactive is telling me that my value is a unit, even though I am obtaining a value as my result.

Comment: @ClementDecker Yes, the type of the `addormult` function is `n:int * what:string -> unit`. It's printing to the console, which returns `unit`, and those expressions are the last expression in each branch. So that becomes the function's return type.

Comment: @Clement Decker, you print to console the value instead of return it from the function. So F# interactive says that the type unit.

Comment: @ClementDecker If you want to return the formatted string instead of printing it to the console, use `sprintf`.

Comment: Thank you!  The OP asked "what am I doing wrong?" not "please refactor my code...", and your answer is what helped/helps novice like me

Answer (score 8):

Really more of an extended comment, but the whole of this code can be simplified by using a `fold` function.

```
let addormult (n, what) =
  let f = if what = "multiply" then (*) else (+)
  List.fold f 1 [1..n]
let x = addormult(4, "multiply") // results in x = 24
let y = addormult(4, "add")      // results in y = 10
```

Or even better, define `getOp` outside the scope, since it's going to be generally applicable.

```
let getOp what = if what = "multiply" then (*) else (+)
let addormult (n, what) = List.fold (getOp what) 1 [1..n]
let x = addormult(4, "multiply") // results in x = 24
let y = addormult(4, "add")      // results in y = 10
```

`fold` is also tail-recursive, ensuring you don't exceed the stack size limit for large N.  In F#, a lot of times when you do recursion, there's already a standard library function that does what you need.  Or if not, sometimes it's better to extract a "general" recursion out of your function and then implement your specific thing in terms of that.

Now, note that strings are not the best way to convey intention here.  Far better to use a *discriminated union* to convey your operation:

```
type Op = Add | Multiply
let getop = function | Multiply -> (*) | Add -> (+)
let addormult (n, what) = List.fold (getop what) 1 [1..n]
let x = addormult(4, Multiply) // results in x = 24
let y = addormult(4, Add)      // results in y = 10
```

That way there's no chance someone could accidentally type "mutliply" and get an unexpected return value.

But really there's no reason to limit to just two operations.  It's straightforward to make this work with any operation:

```
let doOneToN f n = List.fold f 1 [1..n]
let x0 = doOneToN (*) 4 // results in x0 = 24
let y0 = doOneToN (+) 4 // results in y0 = 10
```

With this, you can easily use *partial application* to make specialized functions if you want:

```
let factorial = doOneToN (*)     // the `n` argument is "curried"
let triangularSum = doOneToN (+) // the `n` argument is "curried"
let x1 = factorial 4             // results in x1 = 24
let y1 = triangularSum 4         // results in y1 = 10
```

That's the nice thing about functional programming, is that it's easy to mix and match things.

Of course it's so simple that you might not even care to make a function.  It's almost simpler just to  call `let x = List.fold (*) 1 [1..4]` inline.  Functional-first languages tend to be nice and terse that way.

Answer (score 7):

Prefix: I am no F# expert and someone more knowledgeable than me may be able to provide a more complete answer.

There are a couple of things to fix here:

1. `let rec sum =` is missing a parameter variable declaration.
2. `printfn "%A" product` (and the one for sum) are printing the *functions*, not the values. To correct this, you need to call the function with the arguments.
3. Defining `n` for both the `addormult` tuple value and the recursive value might cause issues - though I am not sure how F# deals with scoping in a situation like this.

This is the "multiply" version after these changes:

```
let addormult (n:int, what:string) = 
if what = "multiply" then 
   let rec product x = 
       if x = 1 then 1
       else x * product(x-1)       
   printfn "product is %A" (product n)
```

And here is the call:

```
let x = addormult (4, "multiply")
```

Which gives me this value:

```
product is 24
```